# Passing line.separator to maven

Tags: java, maven, exec-maven-plugin

I would like to pass `line.separator` to exec plugin but it seems that I do not correctly passing it. I have tried many combinations but could not find the solution. What is the correct way?

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <executable>java</executable>
               <arguments>
                   <argument>-Dline.separator=\n</argument>
                   <argument>-classpath</argument>
                   <classpath />
                   <argument>GeneratorExec</argument>
               </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 3):

That is not going to work. The problem is that the command is executed in a shell. The shell will interpret the `\n` as two characters, not one escaped.

Look at this blog: [Passing '\n' (new-line) on command line in Java](http://geekexplains.blogspot.se/2009/05/passing-n-new-line-on-command-line-in.html).

You will have to let the `GeneratorExec` take the two characters as an argument and then handle it in the program.

Comment: Seems strange. When I pass parameter at command line as `-Dline.separator=$'\n'` with cygwin. its working... Why?

Comment: Maybe exec plugin is calling cmd instead of bash?

Comment: It is actually bash that translates $'\n' to the correct control character 0x0A that will be accepted by java on the command line. It will only work in bash though.