# Maven archetype generates file with windows line breaker

Tags: java, maven

I've a custom maven archetype which generates several projects. This works fine, however when I generate the projects using the archetype, all files are generated using windows line breakers (I'm running on windows).

Even if I add -DargLine="-Dline.separator=$'\n' to the maven command, it does create all files on windows style.

The problem this generates is that some of the files on the project are .sh, and the windows breakers breaks the file and they are useless.

I've already checked and the files inside the archetype.jar are as I defined on my project (unix style).

Is there a way to configure this? I could not find any other possible configuration to define this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was reading other question reggarding maven line.separator, and it turns out I was passing it incorrecly.

The correct way to pass it is -Dline.separator=$'\n', without the -DargLine.

Thanks to @Cemo who commented on this question: [Passing line.separator to maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13288030/passing-line-separator-to-maven)